# What would be the correct way to save "office hours" data?

Tags: javascript

I'm building an app which requires the user to set up their "office hours", meaning the times which they'll be available in.
I'm having trouble thinking of how to set that up properly. When it comes to times and dates, I'd usually save it as a date object or in some cases a timestamp.

What make this different is that I don't need to save a specific time, rather a range of times during the day (and different range for each day).
If I use a simple data/timestamp then it will always be out of range because it will be in the past.

What would be the correct way to store this data?
What I'm building would be used globally, so the timezones are also crucial when checking whether that profile is within office hours or not.

- I don't have any starting code or efforts to show because I don't know how to approach this to begin with.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times

Comment: So you just need `tz, day, hh:mm-hh:mm` ?

Comment: @mplungjan yes, but it needs to be independent of actual epoch time. Comparing the data I have for Sunday for example should be the same for every Sunday either now or in the future

Comment: There is nothing in @mplungjan's example that relates to the epoch or any other particular point in time. An example might be `"America/New_York", "Sunday", "09:00-17:00"`

Comment: @Phil my bad. I thought his question was to get more info before giving a solution, didn't realize that was the solution.

So I just keep these and then manually do the conversions based on timezones? I say manually because when saving in a date format for example, the conversions happen automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider this format. Example is for a user in Sidney

```
{ "tz":["+10:00","en-AU","Australia/Sydney"], // official ISO JS strings
  "weekStart":1, // Monday
  "week": [
   [null,null],  // Sunday
   ["8:30","17:30"],
   ["8:30","17:30"],
   ["8:30","17:30"],
   ["8:30","17:30"],
   ["8:30","17:30"],
   [null,null]
  ]
}
```

It seems you might have to store ST and DST for each and perhaps the switching dates or have that on the server

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_by_country

- Daylight Saving Time AEDT: Australian Eastern Daylight Savings Time   UTC+11
- Standard Time AEST: Australian Eastern Standard Time UTC+10 (current on June 11 2020)

You can use the [INTL datetimeformat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat)  if you do not want to use moment or [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/)

```js
const workHours = { "tz":["+10:00","en-AU","Australia/Sydney"], // official ISO JS strings
      "weekStart":1, // Monday
      "week": [
       [null,null],  // Sunday
       ["08:30","17:30"],
       ["08:30","17:30"],
       ["08:30","17:30"],
       ["08:30","17:30"],
       ["08:30","17:30"],
       [null,null]
      ]
    };

const options = {
  hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric', 
  timeZone: workHours.tz[2],
  timeZoneName: 'short'
};

let now = new Date();

console.log(workHours.tz[2],`${now.toISOString().split("T")[0]}T${workHours.week[now.getDay()][0]}:00.000${workHours.tz[0]}`)
let start = new Date(`${now.toISOString().split("T")[0]}T${workHours.week[now.getDay()][0]}:00.000${workHours.tz[0]}`)
let end   = new Date(`${now.toISOString().split("T")[0]}T${workHours.week[now.getDay()][1]}:00.000${workHours.tz[0]}`)

console.log("UTC",start,end); // usable time

// now working as expected
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat(workHours.tz[1], options).format(start));
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat(workHours.tz[1], options).format(end));
```

Comment: I'd be wary about storing offsets. You'd have to keep them up-to-date with DST

Comment: Ok thank you! That gives me a better understanding of how it's usually done.
@Phil what would you suggest then?

Comment: @Phil I agree. Updated

Comment: @Tsabary TZ identifiers like "America/Anchorage". The [Moment.js TZ](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) library can handle these for you given any particular point in time

Comment: @Tsabary Ihave updated to include the actual offset hours to make it easier to create the time AND to show the time in the locale of the user.

Comment: @Phil Do you agree to the update I made with "+10:00" ?

Comment: @mplungjan but don't the offset change with daylight savings? I find that part to be the most confusing. An what is the purpose of `"en-AU"`?

Comment: To set the formatting - this is only an example for Australians, you would need to set the values per user

Comment: I thought I could rely on the en-AU or the "Australia/Sidney" strings to set the offset, but that is not trivial. You may have to store the DST too